# Unable to add an image to fabric js group

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Hello i am trying to add an image to a group of circle and text, and finally add the group to the canvas but it is failling to show the image.
Can anyone tell me what is the problem ?
Here is the snippets

```js
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
  selection: false
});

const circle = new fabric.Circle({
  left: 100,
  top: 100,
  radius: 50,
  fill: '#eef',
  originX: 'center',
  originY: 'center'
});

const img = new Image();
img.src = '/Content/assets/img/logo.png';
const newImage = new fabric.Image(img, {
    left: circle.left + 15,
    top: circle.top,
    perPixelTargetFind: true,
    padding: 2,
    hasBorders: false,
    hasControls: false,
    width: 20,
    height: 30,
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center',
});


const text = new fabric.Text('Hello World', {
    left: circle.left,
    top: circle.top,
    fontFamily: 'Arial',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 10,
    fill: 'black',
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center',
});

const group = new fabric.Group([circle, text, newImage], {
    left: circle.left,
    top: circle.top,
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center'
});

canvas.add(group);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.0.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="300" style="border: 2px solid green;"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are passing the image object instead of the source. Do this

```
fabric.Image.fromURL('http://placekitten.com/200/300', function(img) {
 canvas.add(img1); 
});
```

```js
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
  selection: false
});

fabric.Image.fromURL('http://placekitten.com/200/300', function(img) {
 var img1 = img.set({ left: 0, top: 0 ,width:200, height:350});
 canvas.add(img1); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.0.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="300" style="border: 2px solid green;"></canvas>
```

`new fabric.Image(img,` here `img` should be a string. Not an Image instance

To add that image in the group, do

```
let ImageInstance;
fabric.Image.fromURL('http://placekitten.com/200/300', function(img) {
   var img1 = img.set({ left: 0, top: 0 ,width:200, height:350});
   ImageInstance = img1;
});
if (ImageInstance){ 
   const group = new fabric.Group([circle, text, ImageInstance], {
       left: circle.left,
       top: circle.top,
       originX: 'center',
       originY: 'center'
   });
   canvas.add(group);
}
```

Comment: how to add that image to a group?

Comment: Here is the issue tho, i have the image in my project under the root folder at this location '/assets/logo.png' and when i try to use your method nothing appear on the canvas. What could be the issue

Comment: Javascript cannot see your server files because it is a client side language. You have to specify an absolute URL. Like `localhost/assets/logo.png` if you are on a local project. @Xris